# Ports stuck after Docker hangs and restarts

Tags: docker

We usually work with certain external containers which we make extensions to. We usually run a docker-compose file with all necessary services.

At times, docker hangs as in doesn't execute commands anymore. We can then force restart docker, and when docker is backup we can do a docker-compose down. However, when we do a docker-compose up back again, we usually have a port conflict issue:

```
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:9081: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

Completely stopping docker or resetting network doesnt work either.

The only solution that works is restarting the PC. Is there any command or something we can use to verify/free those ports?

(Note: This is Docker for Windows, which might very well be a reason for these issues.)

Comment: Please have a look at this article to check free ports. https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28609/how-can-i-tell-what-is-listening-on-a-tcpip-port-in-windows/

Comment: I know which ports are being used, I want Docker to free them without me needing to restart the PC everytime

Comment: Docker will not free the ports for you. You have to free that port